# Class App\\Http\\Controllers\\Api\\v1\\panel\\StorageController does not exist

Tags: php, reactjs, ubuntu, laravel-5, axios

I have a problem with running my project in Ubuntu. I wrote a project and it runs successfully in windows, but when i want to run it in Linux, i faced the error below in network tab in "inspect".

```js
{message: "Class App\Http\Controllers\Api\v1\panel\StorageController does not exist",…}
exception: "ReflectionException"
file: "/home/komail/projects/lara-nakband/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php"
line: 790
message: "Class App\Http\Controllers\Api\v1\panel\StorageController does not exist"
```

I use laravel 5.8 , react js and axios

i use this commands but does not work

```php
composer dump-autoload,
php artisan config:clear
```

in api.php

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

 Route::prefix('v1')->namespace('Api\v1\panel')->group(function (){
    Route::get('/storage/list' , 'StorageController@list');
    Route::get('/storage/chart' , 'StorageController@chart');
    Route::post('/storage' , 'StorageController@storeNewProduct');
    Route::get('/categories' , 'CategoriesController@index');
});
```

in storageController

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api\v1\Panel;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\Storage;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class StorageController extends Controller
{

    public function list(Request $request)
    {
        dd('ssss');
        $products = Storage::get();
        return $products;
    }
```

in List.jsx

```js
componentDidMount(){
        window.axios.get('/api/v1/storage/list')
        .then(response => {
            this.setState({
                storage : response.data
            })
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        })
    }
```

While the code runs without any error in windows, when i call the controller in Linux, there appears no valid answer. in fact, a message appears that explains: the controller does not exist.

Comment: Windows is not case-sensitive, but Linux is. So `namespace('Api\v1\panel')` will not match `namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api\v1\Panel;`

Comment: Why are you using React with laravel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Namespaces are case sensitive. Change

```php
Route::prefix('v1')->namespace('Api\v1\panel')->group(function (){
```

to match the namespace in your controller with a capital "P"

```php
Route::prefix('v1')->namespace('Api\v1\Panel')->group(function (){
```

or vice versa.

You can read about namespacing requirements [here](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/).